# How can I replace a letter in a char array in c?

Tags: c

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

 int main()
 {
    char first[15];
    printf("\n\tWrite here your code");
    scanf("%s",first);
    if()//there is "n" in the char
    //change n with 1
    else
    //quit
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Use [`strchr()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strchr.html) to find the `'n'`.

Comment: `scanf("%s",first);` better as `scanf("%14s",first);` (or research `fgets()`) to avoid buffer overflow.

Comment: "a letter in a char" doesn't make sense because a char *is* a letter

Comment: Juhász Koppány, What should happen if there is more than 1 `'n'` in the string stored in the  `char` array?

Comment: If there is more than 1 "n" change every "n" into 1

Comment: Better to add that detail in the question and not only in a comment here.  Also recommend "How can I replace a letter in a char in c?" --> "How can I replace a letter  one or more times in a string in c?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Such a trivial question deserves a non trivial answer

Note that this approach with branching, demonstrated by @Andy Sukowski-Bang, is - when compiled with `-O3` - roughly **6.5x time slower** than my approach, illustratating the efficiency of bitwise operations over branching instructions (not to mention [Meltdown and Spectre](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/554908/disable-spectre-and-meltdown-mitigations) vulnerabilities and its on branching if mitigations are enabled).

The following program will convert every occurence of the letter `from` to the designated letter.

It is able to replace all characters from `'A' to 'z'` to `'8'` in a string of `8,286,208 bytes` in only **0.07s:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

// gcc -O3 replace.c && ./a.out

void replace(char *s, char from, char to, long n) {
    char eq;
    while (n--) {
        eq = !(*s ^ from);
        *s = !eq * *s + eq * to;
        s++;
    }
}

void replace_branching(char *s, char from, char to, long n) {
    while (n--) {
        if (*s == from)
            *s = to;
        s++;
    }
}

void read_file_to_buffer(FILE *f, long length) {
    char buffer[length + 1];
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    void (*fptr[2]) (char *s, char from, char to, long n) = {replace_branching, replace};

    if (fread (buffer, 1, length, f) ) {
        buffer[length] = '\0';
        fclose (f);

        char subbuff[33];
        subbuff[32] = '\0';
        char from = 'A';
        char to = '8';
        clock_t start, end;
        double cpu_time_used[2];
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
            start = clock();
            for (int i = 0; i < 0x20 + 26; i++) {
                fptr[j](buffer, from + i, to, length);
                //memcpy( subbuff, &buffer[0], 32 );
                //printf("Modified: %s\n", subbuff);
            }
            end = clock();
            cpu_time_used[j] = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
            printf("Time: %fs\n", cpu_time_used[j]);
        }
        printf("Without branching it is %fx faster\n", cpu_time_used[0] / cpu_time_used[1]);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE * f;
    long length;
    if ((f = fopen ("test.txt", "rb"))) // NB: test.txt is a file of 8,286,208 bytes
    {
      fseek (f, 0, SEEK_END);
      read_file_to_buffer(f, ftell(f));
    }
    return 0;
}

/*
    Time: 0.475005s
    Time: 0.070859s
    Without branching it is 6.703524x faster
*/
```

---

#### Some explanations

```
eq = !(*s ^ from); // eq will equal 0 if letters are same, else it will equal 1
*s = !eq * *s + eq * to; // we assign to the pointer its same old value with !eq if the character 'from' was absent, else we will assign the character 'to'.
```

*PS: No malloc were used, I used VLA and it is bad, [very bad](https://lkml.org/lkml/2018/9/3/1288), don't do this at home!*

Answer (score 3):

### Replace character with character

This code will replace every occurrence of the character `'n'` with the character `'1'`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[15];
    printf("Input: ");
    scanf("%14s", str); // prevent buffer overflow

    for (int i = 0; str[i]; ++i) { // iterate over str
        if (str[i] == 'n')
            str[i] = '1';
    }

    printf("Modified: %s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

### Replace character with string

This code will replace every occurrence of the character `'n'` with the string `"1+k"` using the function [strcat](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcat.htm). The modified string is saved to `char mod[]`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[15];
    printf("Input: ");
    scanf("%14s", str); // prevent buffer overflow

    char mod[] = "";

    for (int i = 0; str[i]; ++i) { // iterate over str
        if (str[i] == 'n') {
            char *repl = "1+k";
            strcat(mod, repl); // add "1+k" to mod
        } else {
            strncat(mod, &str[i], 1); // add str[i] to mod
        }
    }

    printf("Modified: %s\n", mod);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can I also printf instead of 1 "k+1"?

Comment: @JuhászKoppány So you wan't to replace the character `'n'` with the string `"k+1"`?

Comment: Yes, I want to replace the character "n" with the string "k+1"

Comment: @JuhászKoppány I have now updated my answer to include the necessary code for replacing a character with a string.